# How to set up icon for a program?

Tags: python, icons, exe, ico

How can i set up icon for my existing program.exe and icon.ico ( in the same folder ) using some sort of hidden (settings) file ?

Edit: i am aware of py2exe CustomIcon option, also about WinRar Sfx ...

Question is: it is possible in this specific way i described ?

Comment: in what programing language is your program made?

Comment: @Gabe: i am not working with visual studio...   @FeRtoll: made in python created with py2exe ( py2exe can do it ) but i want it in a way i descibed... it should be independent of how that exe was created, only by a single line in that setting file... @Paul Windows (Xp,Vista,7)

Comment: Do you want others to tell you how to do this, or do you already know the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read py2exe doc:
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/CustomIcons

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

If you dont have winrar then install it!

Then right click on your program.exe and select "Add to archive...", under "Archiving options" select "Create SFX Archive". Now go to tab "Advanced" and click on "SFX Options" on "General tab" setup all you need and add "Run after extraction" (yourprogram.exe) under "Modes" tab select "Hide All" under silent groupbox, go to "Update" tab and select "Update Mode" (Extract and replace files) and "Overwrite mode" (Overwrite all files) now go to "TextAndIcon" tab and put to title yourprogram.exe name and under "Load SFX icon from the file" add an icon you want! Click OK, and click OK again. Now wait to compile and you have your program with icon!

Just have to watch where you want it to be installed, or if it doesnt have any install direction then you use "Unpack to temporary folder" under the "Modes" tab in "SFX Options"!

Think this will help you! :)

Comment: Thanks, but i know about SFX option in WinRar, it is shurely a solution, but i think it can be be done as i described, cannt it ?

Comment: dont think so... i mean everithing is possible... its just about you want do it hard or easy way! ;)