# Set an icon for a .exe file

Tags: python, icons, exe, python-3.3, cx-freeze

I've made a .exe file of a game I made in Python, but I'm not sure how to make that exe file have an icon, because it looks dull and boring. I want to somehow make the icon be a picture of an asteroid let's say, because I made the game asteroids. I used cx_freeze to compile it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up icon for a program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915202/how-to-set-up-icon-for-a-program)

Comment: @Tasos I used cx_freeze and that person used py2exe

Comment: If there wasn't any edit option, I could swear it wasn't there before! Maybe I need a coffee before stackoverflow. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Tasos I found out how to, never mind, it's in the setup.py file :)

Comment: @Infamouslyuseless : please do post what you found out - it helps other people who might read this when they have the same problem.

Comment: @ThomasK ok Sorry... shall i delete the comment then?

Comment: @Infamouslyuseless : the comments fine - I meant to say: write it up as a proper answer showing what you had to add to setup.py (and maybe explain why Blender's answer didn't work for you).

Comment: ok, i'll do it when i get back from school

Answer (score 4):

Add it to the options in your `setup.py` file:

```
setup(
    ...
    options={
        "build_exe": {
            "icon": "path/to/icon.ico"
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: This isn't working for me and I don't see any reference to an icon parameter for build_exe options in the docs. https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe

Answer (score 0):

**This is easier to understand!**

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
   base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("example.pyw", base=base)]

cx_Freeze.setup(
name = "SeaofBTC-Client",
options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter",],"icon":"example.ico"}},
version = "0.01",
description = "Sea of BTC trading application",
executables = executables
)
```